# Oracle select from values and substract from last value

Tags: oracle, select

Need help on Oracle `SELECT` statement.
I Have table like this with used days. User can have 11 days

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+
| ID | NAME     | USED| DATE      |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+ 
|  1 | John     |  1  |01/01/2018 |
|  2 | John     |  2  |01/03/2018 |
|  3 | John     |  2  |01/05/2018 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+
```

So on `QUERY SELECT` i want to have result of left days like this

```
+----+----------+------+-----------+
| ID | NAME     | DAYS | USED| LEFT| 
+----+----------+------+-----------+ 
|  1 | John     |  11  |  1  |  10 | 
|  2 | John     |  10  |  2  |  8  | 
|  3 | John     |  8   |  2  |  6  | 
+----+----------+------+-----------+
```

Any help how to achieve this result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing you need is the analytic version of `sum`. Also, try not to use Oracle keywords (like `date`) as column names.

```
-- sample data
with ex as (select 1 as id, 'John' as name, 1 as used, to_date('01/01/2018','mm/dd/yyyy') as date1 from dual
            union select 2 as id, 'John' as name, 2 as used, to_date('01/03/2018','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
            union select 3 as id, 'John' as name, 2 as used, to_date('01/05/2018','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual)
-- main query
select id, 
    name, 
    11-sum(used) over (partition by name order by date1) + used as days, 
    used, 
    11-sum(used) over (partition by name order by date1) as left
from ex;
```

Output:

```
        ID NAME       DAYS       USED       LEFT
---------- ---- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 John         11          1         10
         2 John         10          2          8
         3 John          8          2          6
```